# iBus preferences is not shown in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, ibus

iBus Preferences is not shown in Ubuntu 13.10, I already configured iBus to add new keyboard but it is not showing. ibus-setup command and it only shows next input method, there is not enable and disable option, how to fix this :)